# Internal Link not working in Body Text with PortableTextToReact

Tags: next.js, sanity

I followed [this guide](https://www.sanity.io/guides/portable-text-internal-and-external-links) on creating an internalLink type to be used within body text for linking to other posts etc.

It states to use the `mark` however that is undefined, I can get `data` which returns the following

```
{
    "_key": "1c0ae3f78bac",
    "_type": "internalLink",
    "reference": {
        "_ref": "b8f67695-00e4-4906-8ba4-9c51faf093fb",
        "_type": "reference"
    }
}
```

How do I get the reference to be the `slug.current` of the actual post it is referencing to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to make sure you're following the reference (`->`) in the GROQ query when you're [querying the links](https://www.sanity.io/guides/portable-text-internal-and-external-links#b0847aaef91a).

Comment: I should have realised this, I’ve had to use that method of following the reference before for some reason I didn’t think it would work the same way in body text